# Any way to run my android project from Android Studio on my phone?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I want to download the oem driver for my phone: Infinix hot s - x521,
from :
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html?utm_source=udacity&utm_medium=course&utm_campaign=android_basics#Drivers

But the OEM Drivers table doesn't exist it

Any idea about resolving this case?

Comment: Also check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html) and serach for drivers on the internet!

Comment: which os you are working on??

Comment: Must use OEM Driver, Windows 8.1

Comment: Just  install usb drivers connect your device enable usb  debugging on your device ..you can run your project on your device..see the link i provided to download usb drivers...

Answer (score 0):

Download Infinix USB drivers from below link given here (based on your model number), install it in your computer and connect your Infinix device with PC or Laptop successfully.
https://freeandroidroot.com/download-infinix-usb-drivers/

Since Infinix doesn’t offer PC suite software, downloading and installing the USB driver in your computer is the only way to connect your Infinix smartphone or tablet with your PC or Laptop computer.

**Note:*All these USB drivers are windows based drivers. So, don’t try to install them on Mac or Linux-based computers.***

Hope this will help!!!